# eshell: Is there an existing method of redirecting output to a buffer and then show the buffer in the other window when done?

Tags: eshell

It seems like this would be a ubiquitous desire: capture the output of a command in eshell into a new buffer and when the command is completed, show the buffer in the other window.  For example, I just did:

```
rails g scaffold --help > #<scaffold>
```

and then I did `C-x 4 b scaffold` although `view-buffer-other-window` is probably more what I want here.

Is there already an existing syntax to do this?  If not, I'm thinking adding a plus sign:

```
rails g scaffold --help > #+<scaffold>
```

It appears that I use `eshell-parse-argument-hook` to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In eshell, you can redirect `stdout` to an emacs buffer in a few different ways.

```bash
rails g scaffold --help > (switch-to-buffer "*scaffold*")
rails g scaffold --help >>> #<*scaffold*>
```

You can name the buffer whatever you want, and it'll be autovivified if it doesn't already exist.  You can read more about it at the following links:

- [Eshell: Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Redirection)
- [EmacsWiki: Emacs Pipe](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsPipe#h5o-3)